# AVPlayer with AVPlayerLayer 'ready to play' status no work for the real videoView display

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have a AVPlayer with remote video source. using `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` to detect the `readyToPlay` status is on and set the AVPlayerLayer to myVideoContainerView's layer for display.

the problem is: after the `readyToPlay` status is trigger. it delay for 1-2 seconds for the video showed on screen for real.

I have tried to set AVPlayerLayer before and after the `readyToPlay` state is on. but non of them works.

the problem only occurs when I use `AVPlayer+AVPlayerLayer`. using `AVPlayerViewController` is fine. but I still need to solve this condition in my project.

thanks for any suggestion!

```
     @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myVideoContainter;
     @property AVPlayer *player;
     @property AVPlayerLayer *layer;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
     self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithUR:videoURL];
     [self.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
if (object == self.player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
    if (self.player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
        NSLog(@"Ready To Play");
        self.layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
        self.layer.frame = self.mainContentView.bounds;
        [self.mainContentView.layer addSublayer:self.layer];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem sovled.

don't know why but `player.currentItem.status` is more accurate then `player.status`.

```
[self.player.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if(self.player.currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay){
        //do something        
    }
}
```

note. some action will change `AVPlayerItem.status`. should handling looping issue this way.